# MacOS Mouse pointer flashing with signals and QLineEdit blinking cursor

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, macos-mojave

I am developing a small media player application using PyQt5 on MacOS Mojave.  Any time the mouse is hovering over a widget where the mouse pointer changes shape, the mouse pointer begins to blink (flash?), changing shape between the normal mouse pointer and the alternate mouse pointer.

For example, if I create a QLineEdit widget the mouse pointer changes to an I-Beam as the alternate pointer when hovering over the widget.  Ordinarily this the mouse pointer simply changes shape so long as I am hovering over the widget.  However, in the below test application the mouse pointer continually changes shape between the I-Beam pointer and the normal arrow mouse pointer, changing back and forth at the same rate as the input position cursor in the widget.

Here is a screen recording showing the problem. Note how the mouse pointer changes shape between an arrow an an I-Beam as the text entry cursor blinks, as I type, and as I select text.

[image: Mouse Flicker Screen Recording]

Example code showing this behavior on my system:

```
import sys
from PyQt5               import QtWidgets
from PyQt5               import QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400,400)
        self.cw = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.cw)
        self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.cw)
        self.l.addWidget(self.le)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.l.addWidget(self.label)
        self.show()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([sys.argv])
w=MainWindow()
app.setActiveWindow(w)
exit_code = app.exec_()

sys.exit(exit_code)
```

In the above code I can fix the problem by disabling the line edit cursor flash using `app.setCursorFlashTime(0)`.  However, this does NOT fix the problem in my application.  In my application, signals in other widgets will also cause the same mouse pointer shape changing (blinking) behavior.

Version details:
**MacOS** Mojave 10.14.5
**PyQt5** 5.12.2
**Python** 3.7.3

I have developed QtApplications in the past and never observed this behavior and am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Does anyone have a solution for this highly irritating behavior?

EDIT: Change "mouse cursor" to "mouse pointer" for clarity.
EDIT: Updated to MacOS 10.14.5 and problem still exists.
EDIT: Add a screen recording to make the problem more clear.

Comment: FYI:

I tried the above experiment on a new account.  same problem.
I posted the problem to the pyqt mailing list and got a response, "works fine for me".

Seems to indicate my computer has a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

This is a bug in Qt:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75552

It appears this is a bug in 5.12.2 and 5.12.3  Installing 5.12.1 fixed the mouse pointer, and I assume 5.12.4 will also be fixed.